# How to count number of lines with HTTP code based on pattern in the previous line

Tags: http, logging, awk, pattern-matching

I have log file there request and response are on different lines.
First line:

```
[29/01/2018 16:23:49.900] GET http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?tid=UA-1234567-3....
```

Second line:

```
 [29/01/2018 16:23:49.976] response: status = HTTP/1.0 200 OK, contentLength=35, contentType=image/gif, responseBodySize=35
```

I need to count HTTP codes like (200, 500, 400) from second line for all requests based on pattern for first line (for example for UA-1234567-3 and for UA-1234567-4)

Could somebody give me a right awk or grep command to do this. Thanks!

Comment: its not clear that there is anything in line2 that links it to `UA-1234567-4` OR can you guarantee that they will always appear in the file next to each other? Please edit your Q rather than replying in comments. I'll delete this comment if you "fix" your Q. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If your actual output is same as shown sample one then following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '/response: status/{match($0,/HTTP[^,]*/);print substr($0,RSTART+9,RLENGTH-9)}' Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** Adding a non-one liner form with explanation too here:

```
awk '
/response: status/{                   ##Checking condition here if a line is having string response: status in it then do following:
  match($0,/HTTP[^,]*/);              ##Using match utility of awk where I am writing regex to match from string HTTP to till the first occurrence of comma.
  print substr($0,RSTART+9,RLENGTH-9) ##Printing the substring whose starting value is RSTART+9 and end value is RLENGTH+9, where RSTART and RLENGTH are out of the box variables of awk and their values will be set once a regex is matched in match keyword.
}
' Input_file                          ##Mentioning the Input_file name which awk has to parse/read.
```